# debugging play! framework, getting rid of JRE source files

Tags: eclipse, debugging, playframework

I'm debugging play! framework with eclipse in order to learn what happens inside...

But every every once in a while I come up looking at ClassLoader.class source file or someting similar

It seems like the JRE sources are attached...

Do you know how can I tell eclipse to ignore them, and just let me debug thru play framework sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on Eclipse go to Preferences > Java > Debug > activate Step Filtering. You will see a list of packages. ClassLoader is there and selected by default when you enable the filtering.

That should do it.